# Cannot resolve host from Private Build Agent using Team Services

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, devops

I am using a private build agent together with Azure Team Services. I have a Build task that works and publishes a build artifact. Within a Release task I have a command prompt that makes a ping to a server.

```
Tool: ping 
Arguments: MyServerXXX
```

But when I run the Release the task fails with the error:

```
2017-06-01T12:51:48.4030953Z ##[command]ping MyServerXXX
2017-06-01T12:51:48.6090956Z Ping request could not find host MyServerXXX. Please check the name and try again.
```

The Build Agent and MyServerXXX are a part of the same domain, I am able to log onto the build server and ping MyServerXXX. The Build Agent is running under a domain account that has access to MyServerXXX. I have also tried a fully qualified name.

The same command works when added to the Build definition.
How can I make this work in the Release pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on the Run on Agent and changing the Deployment Queue from Hosted to Default solved the problem.